How to pass parameter and state values to FMU using fmusim from a file in bulk?
We have a rather large FMU (50MB or so) written in C. We have the default values of parameters, states and inputs for our model defined in the FMI2/3.xml file as well as in the setStartValues() function which gets called during the FMU initialization. How can we pass parameter and state values through fmusim (https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs) in bulk?
I tried the following:

Use the --input-file option. This works for inputs but does not work for parameters/states.
Use the --start-value argument to fmusim and pass individual named pairs of params like --start-value "param-name" "param-value" (double quotes are important). This works. However, I have over 4000 values, I would like to be configurable from the simulation environment and the above approach results in rather a large command that is too long for command prompt and it gives a command too long error.
I also tried the --initial-fmu-state-file but the example in tests generates this file from --final-fmu-state-file and this results in a binary file that is not human editable.

Any suggestions on what can be tried, or how to pass parameters/states as file would be helpful.

With fmusim from the Reference FMUs I currently do not see a solution.
I suggest you open an issue there with a feature request. https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/issues, and perhaps link to this Stackoverflow topic.
Are you bound to use FMUSim?
Or could you e.g. use fmpy? There, if the simulate_fmu function is not sufficient, you could easily modify it by creating you own script to set your thousands of paramters.
If your simulation tool supports the SSP Standard, https://ssp-standard.org/, you can create an SSP file containing your FMU and parameter files.
In the future the FMI Project plans to create a layered standard on top of FMI that allows you amongst other things to include SSP parameter files directly in the FMU, see https://github.com/pmsfit/fmi-ls-ref for a draft.
Regarding setting the complete state for FMUs: this is in a binary format by design, see https://fmi-standard.org/
Setting continuous states is possible for ME FMUs, but not for CS FMUs, see https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/issues/94
